# Ant Design form set values form props

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, antd, react-props

I'm using `antd` design in my form.

Here I'm setting value from reducer `profilereducer` by using `shouldComponentUpdate` method.

```
class ProfileForm extends Component {

 componentDidMount = () => {
  this.props.actions.getprofile()
 }

 shouldComponentUpdate = (nextProps) => {
  if (this.props.profile) {
   this.props.form.setFieldsValue({
    name: this.props.profile.name,
   });
  } else {
   this.props.form.setFieldsValue({
    firstname: 'loading',
   });
  }
 }


 render() {
  const { getFieldDecorator, getFieldValue } = this.props.form; 
     <Form layout="vertical">
        <FormItem label="First Name" >
            {getFieldDecorator('name', { rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Required!', }], })(
                <Input addonBefore={selectBefore} placeholder="First Name" />
            )}
        </FormItem>
    </Form>    
}


 function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
   profile: state.profilereducer.profile,
  }
 }

 function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
   actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  }
 }

 const Profile = Form.create()(ProfileForm);

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Profile);
}
```

**Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting state in a loop, hence you got the error. Here is a better approach of dealing it.. I just left selectBefore as a variable(in your code, i haven't found setting it).. Change it to string if you get error..

```
componentDidMount = () => {
   this.props.actions.getprofile()
  }

  renderBasicform(initialVal) {
    const { getFieldDecorator, getFieldValue } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <Form layout="vertical">
        <FormItem label="First Name" >
          {getFieldDecorator('name', { initialValue: initialVal,rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Required!', }], })(
            <Input addonBefore={selectBefore} placeholder="First Name" />
          )}
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    );
  }

  render() {
    if(!this.props.profile) {
        return (
          <div>
          {this.renderBasicform("Loading")}
          </div>
        );
    }

        return (
          <div>
            {this.renderBasicform(this.props.profile.name)}
            </div>
        );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the function name hints at, the `shouldComponentUpdate` should return a boolean. Either it should return true if `render()` should be called (which is normally the default), or false if not. It is mainly intended as an optimization function, where the developer can skip re-rendering the component in certain circumstances. See the react documentation for example the function: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Secondly, I am note sure why you even want to do a remapping between `profile` and `form`. It is generally considered an anti-pattern to mutate or change properties directly inside the component classes like this. Is there a particular reason why you are trying to remap the `profile` data to the `form` property? Would it not be simpler to either construct that mapping the render function and pass it to the  `<Form>` there? Or better yet, have the reducer map this data as you would like to have it from the start, without having to properties with similar data but different structure.